# Pattern compile(String regex, int flags) flags for what?

Tags: java, regex

I am a little bit confused with this code below:

```
public class RegularEx {
    public static void main(String... arg) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("M+", 5);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("M Merit Match MM m mM");
        while (matcher.find())
            System.out.print(matcher.group() + " ");
    }
}
```

in this part  `Pattern.compile("M+", 5);`

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-int- the number should represent flags that may include CASE_INSENSITIVE, MULTILINE, DOTALL, UNICODE_CASE, CANON_EQ, UNIX_LINES, LITERAL, UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS and COMMENTS

amount them , 5 should represent what?

Source:
https://java.meritcampus.com/core-java-questions/Regular-Expression?t=195

Comment: You can call the statics from `Pattern`, like: `Pattern.DOTALL` or if you want to combine them: `Pattern.DOTALL | CASE_INSENSITIVE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 is a combination of 1 (UNIX_LINES) and 4 (COMMENTS), the full list of the constants can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.regex.Pattern.CANON_EQ).

```
java.util.regex.Pattern
Modifier and Type   Constant Field  Value
public static final int CANON_EQ    128
public static final int CASE_INSENSITIVE    2
public static final int COMMENTS    4
public static final int DOTALL  32
public static final int LITERAL 16
public static final int MULTILINE   8
public static final int UNICODE_CASE    64
public static final int UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS 256
public static final int UNIX_LINES  1
```

Never specify flags like that, instead do

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("M+", UNIX_LINES | COMMENTS);
```